# Using super.paint() won't show anything

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint, paintcomponent

I know this is probably simple, but it is causing me trouble. When I use paint(), it shows nothing, and if I use paintComponent(), it shows an error (cannot find symbol). What am I doing wrong?

This is an example of using paint():

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.awt.*; 

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        // define the position
        int locX = 200;
        int locY = 200;

        // draw a line (there is now drawPoint..)
        g.drawLine(locX, locY, locX, locY); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test(); 
    }
}
```

Comments say this is a nice and simple code but I can't see anything because it shows nothing.

[SOLVED]
To all who answered, thanks. LOL at me bros, I really didn't notice that there was a tiny dot. Awesome dude, thanks.

Comment: Works on mine... The dot is 1 by 1 pixel so you really need to look at it closely to see. For a greater effect, change the drawLine() function to `g.fillRect(locX - 2, locY - 2, 4, 4)`.

Comment: @CPUTerminator is it still in coordinate(200,200)? and you just made it bigger?

Comment: Yep. Used the method `fillRect()` instead to draw a filled "rectangle" instead of a line. Width and Height are both 4 pixels. Its not exactly perfectly centered on 200, 200, use `g.fillRect(locX - 2, locY - 2, 5, 5)` for that.

Answer (score 3):

You code is not the recommended way of doing things, but that aside, it works.

You do not set a color to paint with, and you draw a single dot. You probably just didnt see it (I had to look twice). It draw a single black pixel at 200, 200.

Answer (score 2):

I would bet the problem is that you're only drawing a single point, so it's hard to see. Your code works fine for me.

However, you should be extending JPanel, not JFrame. Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/